# Comparar 2 columnas en DataGridview

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo 2 `DataGridview` que cargan información desde una base de datos en MySQL, en el `dataA` tengo horarios, con una columna hora y un dato del tipo: 09:30 (`String`) y en el `dataB` tengo los datos de las citas asignadas para el día con su columna hora (`String`) y el mismo formato del toro grid *(ya que al reservar la hora, se hace con los datos de ese grid)*.

Lo que tengo que hacer es una comparación entre las columnas `hora` de ambos grid, y de esta manera, bloquear en el `gridA` (el de las horas) la fila con la hora que ya esta ocupada (que vendría siendo la hora que aparezca en el `gridB`).

El código que uso para hacer una comparación es el siguiente:

```
//COMAPRAR SI EL CLICK VIENE DESDE EL METODO DE EDICION
if (variable == "prueba")
{
    //MessageBox.Show("DESHABILITA LA COMPARACION POR HORA");
    this.txtHorarioCita.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dgvHorarios.CurrentRow.Cells["hora"].Value);
    this.lblIDHora.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dgvHorarios.CurrentRow.Cells["idHora"].Value);

}
else
{
    this.txtHorarioCita.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dgvHorarios.CurrentRow.Cells["hora"].Value);
    this.lblIDHora.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dgvHorarios.CurrentRow.Cells["idHora"].Value);
    this.verificarHora();
}
```

y el método `verificarHora` lo tengo así:

```
private void verificarHora()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvConsultasDia.Rows) //dgvConsultasDia.Rows
    {

        string horaAtencion = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["hora"].Value);

        if (horaAtencion == this.txtHorarioCita.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("LA HORA SELECCIONADA ESTA OCUPADA", "CENTRO MEDICO CHILHUE", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            hora = "";
            //this.label18.Visible = true;
            //this.label1.Visible = false;
            this.groupBox1.Enabled = false;
            this.groupBox2.Enabled = false;

            return;

        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("la hora sel", "CENTRO MEDICO CHILHUE", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //this.habilitarControles(true);
            //this.groupBox1.Enabled = true;
            this.groupBox2.Enabled = true;

            this.btnGuardar.Enabled = true;
            this.txtRutPaciente.Enabled = true;
            //this.label1.Visible = true;
            //this.label18.Visible = false;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

La variable `prueba` viene desde un botón de edición, y funciona, pero una sola vez, si vuelvo a repetir el proceso luego que se encuentra un registro repetido, ya no funciona y me da el pase al `insert` con la hora ya existente.

Saludos a todos, agradezco desde ya cualquier ejemplo u orientación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No logro captar del todo lo que deseas hacer, por lo tanto solo te daré sugerencias sobre lo que puedes hacer.

1) Para obtener valores de una celda de un DGV usas lo siguiente:

```
dataA.Rows[index].Cells["hora"].Value.ToString()
```

donde el `index` el es número de la fila (Puede hacer una iteración con un `for` si fuera necesario, como dije antes, no logro captar del todo lo que deseas realizar).

2) Como segunda recomendación te aconsejaría un campo (tipo `bool`) nombrémosla `horaOcupada` en el grid que te permita saber qué registro está "bloqueado" y cuales no. `true` = ocupada, `false` = Libre

3)Teniendo los valores de ambos DGV puedes compararlos de la siguiente manera:

```
if (dataA.Rows[index].Cells["hora"].Value.ToString().equals(dataB.Rows[index].Cells["hora"].Value.ToString()))
dataA.Rows[index].Cells["horaOcupada"].Value = true;
```

Ante cualquier duda o comentario, estamos a la orden.

Comment: hola @Ricardo, gracias por tu tiempo, lo que necesito hacer es que si en la grilla B LA HORA 09:45 aparece(es decir, esa hora ya esta ocupada porque fue registrada) no se muestre en las horas disponibles (grilla A), porque actualmente lo que hago es que al pinchar en una hora de la grilla A, hace una busqueda con ese valor (por ejemplo 09:45) y si esta en la grilla B muestra un mensaje, igual estaria bien, pero si vuelvo a hacer el proceso, la validacion ya no funciona y me deja insertar nuevamente con la misma hora, deje en la pregunta el codigo que ocupo actualmente

Comment: Bueno, En ese caso, primero "carga" con datos la grilla B y luego obten los valores de la columna "hora" y concatenalas, por ejemplo: horascubiertas="9:00, 11:00.."  etc... Después para cargar la grilla A usa el valor de esta variable y utilizala para hacer un filtro en el SELECT con que "llenas" la grilla A. No sé como se llama tu campo de la BBDD pero supondré que se llama hora. Entonces sería: (Además de todos tu otros filtros) AND hora NOT IN horascubiertas (todos los valores qe ya estás en la grilla B).